# Getting FirebaseVisionImage from manipulated image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to do some pre-processing in my image before using Firebase MLkit. Previously, I was simply loading my image and then passing it directly like this.

```
File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.IMAGE);
final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(file);
VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);
```

But now, I wanted to do some processing on the image. I did this using Flutter's [Image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) like this.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;

File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.IMAGE);
Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
var img = Img.invert(image);
```

Now, how do I pass this new object to FirebaseVisionImage. I see that there is this function:

```
FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(bytes, metadata)
```

I'm guessing I can get bytes from the above image object using `img.getBytes()` but I'm confused how to set the metadata.

EDIT:
I see that one can write the image to a temporary file doing

```
img.writeAsBytesSync(decoded.ToList());
```

and then use that image again using `FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile()` but I would really prefer not to do that.